# Pythom programming how can I exclude the values for if statement from the dictionary list with loop

Tags: python, xcode, loops, dictionary, if-statement

How can I write orders with loop, dictionary and if statement by python
If I want the output result from dictionary list and for the others input print a sentence
Here is my program could someone find what is the solution for the mistakes

```
def phone_guide():

    guide_number = input("Enter a number:")
    
    numbers = {"Amal": 1111111111, "Mohammed": 2222222222, "Khadijah": 3333333333, "Abdullah": 4444444444}
    
    While guide_number == 1111111111:
        print("Amal")
    
    elif guide_number == 2222222222:
        print("Mohammed")
    
    elif guide_number == 3333333333:
        print("khadijah")
    
    elif guide_number == 4444444444:
        print("Abdullah")
    
    elif guide_number != numbers:
        print("Sorry, the number is not found")
    
    #This mean the number has to be from the dictionary list
    
    else:
    print("This is invalid number")
    
    #This mean if the number less or more than 10 number or different value or string 
phone_guide()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues you need to fix. The indentation is wrong and the loop has issues. You need to iterate over the dictionary and check if value exists.

```
def phone_guide():

    print "Enter a number:"
    guide_number = input()

    numbers = {"Amal": 1111111111, "Mohammed": 2222222222, "Khadijah": 3333333333, "Abdullah": 4444444444}

    for key,value in numbers.items():
        if guide_number == value:
            print(key)
            return
    print("Sorry, the number is not found")

phone_guide()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, its unneccessarily complicated to store `name: number` if you want to check the number. Is it possible to reverse it like `number: name`?
`numbers = {1111111111: "Amal", 2222222222: "Mohammed", ...}`

Secondary you don't need all these if/elif/else statements. You can check if an item is in a dictionaries keys or values.
`1111111111 in numbers.keys()` or `1111111111 in numbers.values()`

To match your phone numbers validity you can use a regex like this and check if `typeof(phone_number) == int`.

```py
import re
invalid = 1234568
valid = 0123456789
re.match(r'\d+{10}', valid)
>>> True
re.match(r'\d+{10}', invalid)
>>> False
```

Given all these information you should be able to come to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code. Go through the basics of python again.

```
def phone_guide():

  guide_number = int(input("Enter a number:"))

  numbers = {"Amal": 1111111111, "Mohammed": 2222222222, "Khadijah": 3333333333, "Abdullah": 4444444444}

  for key, value in numbers.items():
    if guide_number == value:
      return key

  return "This is invalid number"
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def phone_guide():
    guide_number = input("Enter a number:")
    numbers = {"Amal": 1111111111, "Mohammed": 2222222222, "Khadijah": 3333333333, "Abdullah": 4444444444}
    if guide_number == 1111111111:
        print("Amal")
    elif guide_number == 2222222222:
        print("Mohammed")
    elif guide_number == 3333333333:
        print("khadijah")
    elif guide_number == 4444444444:
        print("Abdullah")
    elif guide_number != numbers:
        print("Sorry, the number is not found")
    else:
        print("This is invalid number")
```

Write your code as above. In python you can only use elif after if.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).